# Cloud 9 terminal not in /workspace

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide

While freeing up some space on my Cloud 9 workspace, my terminal froze and stopped responding. I restarted the workspace but that only seemed to make it worse. The last thing I remember doing was accidentally deleting the /tmp/ folder in my workspace.

The terminal does not have a spinning logo next to it, it looks like it's  completely loaded but isn't in the workspace directory.
Here is what the terminal looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZvtY.png

I have tried:

- Using a different browser
- Restarting the workspace
- Restarting all terminal sessions
- Opening a new terminal
- Killing all processes in the process list
- Cloning my workspace
- Pressing Ctrl + q
- Resetting my workspace with '?reset=1'

Other workspaces seem to function as expected with a functioning terminal.

I have made a post on the official C9 support forums and I have contact C9 support directly but I have not received a response on either platform.

If anyone has a solution to this I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a response from Cloud 9, I was told I need to download my workspace files and move them to a new workspace. After doing that everything seems to work normally now.